# How it really is... 5.6 Apps cannot use Push Notifications to send advertising, promotions, or direct marketing of any kind?

Tags: ios, app-store, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Yes,

This rule clearly states that any advertising or marketing activity by Push Notification could cost your a ban in App Store.

So how about Groupon and other special offer focused apps? Each day I receive notifications from Groupon with clear marketing content, and when I open it I'm redirected into the view with big "Buy" button (Btw. do you know any other live apps using push in similar way? I mean not exact Groupon-clone apps).

Ofcourse user need to have a choice if he wants to receive such notifications or not, and from who (like in Groupon you can choose subscribed cities), privacy policy need to clearly state what kind of notifications user will receive. Maybe the frequency of notifications does matter (1 per day for Groupon)?

Ok lets get back to the point of my question:

**Whats the receipe for such app which explicitly bends the 5.6 rule to stays up and running in App Store?**

**Have you ever trying to submit similar application?**

Comment: Another app I've found BuyVia - it sends you immediate push notification, when special offer matched with created ShopAlert shows up.

Comment: Lets say, I cut my in app purchase by 30%, does this mean I can't put a notification saying There is a deal today?

Answer (score 2):

App reviews rules are not strict, since Groupon is just that, an advertisement platform, an app is expected to send these kind of push notification. 
But if, for example, the Facebook app would be using push notification to tell there users to download some other app the rulle 5.6 will come in to play.

But just that some other app got approved does in no way mean that you app will, even if it has the same functionality. So the answer you are seeking for will not do you any good, since even if someone got there app approved will not mean you will get it approved.